# Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL Google Translate API

Tags: java, api, google-translate

i'm using google translate api for Java.
 
When i'm tried to get translate from code i got the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://translate.google.com.br/translate_a/single?client=t&sl=auto&tl=pt&hl=en&dt=bd&dt=ex&dt=ld&dt=md&dt=qc&dt=rw&dt=rm&dt=ss&dt=t&dt=at&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&otf=1&rom=1&ssel=0&tsel=3&kc=1&tk=620730|996163&q=Try%20mWinMgr%20=%20(WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);int%20displayWidth%20=%20mWinMgr.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();where%20context%20is%20Context%20instance.By%20default,%20the%20FrameLayout%20in%20which%20your%20layout%20is%20kept,%20fills%20the%20whole%20display%20horizontally%20(vertically%20you%20can%20have%20status%20bar).%20So%20you%20can%20set%20the%20maximum%20possible%20width%20by%20using%20android:layout_width="fill_parent"%20correctly.
```

My url conntection object is define:

```
urlConn = url.openConnection();

urlConn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");
```

Any suggestions please?

API Using code:

```
translate.translate(text, Language.ENGLISH,
            Language.PORTUGUESE);
```

**An error occurred only in the last week.
Before that everything works fine with the same code**

Comment: A 403 is a `forbidden` error.  Are you sure that you are using the API properly?

Comment: Hey, an error occurred only in the last week
Before that everything works fine with the same code

Comment: Does it work in a browser? Is that an official Translate API URL or one you determined from the web page interface? If its the latter its subject to change/blocking at anytime

Comment: No, the link isn't works also in browser. yes it's the offical Translate API from google site (google-api-translate-java-0.97)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, using the updated API (you need a key): http://hayageek.com/google-translate-api-tutorial/#java-example

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the URL being generated is malformed. The library you are using is also an out-of-date library from the Google Code [archive](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-api-translate-java/). It likely was working by coincidence, but you just now exposed a problem.

Please use the current version of the Translate API Client, available [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/translate/v2).

Comment: Yes, Translate is a paid service, see https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/pricing. If you need free translation for a site consider using the Website Translator Gadget - https://translate.google.com/manager/website/.

Comment: Alternatively, **Bing translator** API provides free 2M characters monthly.

Comment: @Adam,@Bashher H,  Thanks, I'm looking for free translate api. i'm using also in bing but i'm looking for another. (i'm using Java)